# Error: expected an identifier while compiling a program of cusp which is opensource library of CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

The basic idea is to do sparse matrix-vector multiplication(SpMV) with [CUSP](https://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) under Compressed Sparse Row(CSR) Compressed format ,the code is below:

the code of csr.cu

```
#include <string.h>
#include "fileproc.h"
#include <cusp/csr_matrix.h>
#include <cusp/detail/device/spmv/csr_vector.h>
#define VALUETYPE float
#define INDEXTYPE int
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
 string file=argv[1];
 INDEXTYPE m;
 INDEXTYPE n;
 INDEXTYPE nnz;
 INDEXTYPE * rowA,*colA;
 VALUETYPE * valA;
 readFile(file,colA,rowA,valA,m,n,nnz);     
 //the code will be omitted because of too much of them     
 return 0;
}
```

the code of fileproc.h

```
#ifndef _FILEPROC_H_
#define _FILEPROC_H_
    
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
/*triples for storing original data from files */

template <class T, class ITYPE>
struct Triple
{
    ITYPE row;  //  row index
    ITYPE col;  //  col index
    T val;      //  value
};  

/*counting the nonzeros along the rows*/
template <typename ITYPE>
ITYPE CumulativeSum (ITYPE * arr, ITYPE size)
{
     ITYPE prev;
     ITYPE tempnz = 0 ;
     for (ITYPE i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
     {
        prev = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tempnz;
        tempnz += prev ;    
     }
     return (tempnz) ;          // return sum
}
/*convert the matrix to triples*/
template <typename T,typename ITYPE>
void Triple_init(std::string fileName,Triple<T,ITYPE> *A)
{
    ITYPE flops;
    //cout <<"reading input matrix in text(ascii).."<<endl;
    int m,n,nnz;
    std::ifstream infile(fileName.c_str());
    char line[256];
    char c=infile.get();
    while(c=='%')
    {
        infile.getline(line,256);
        c=infile.get();
    }
    infile.unget();
    infile>>m>>n>>nnz;      
    flops=nnz*2;
    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        ITYPE cnz=0;
        while (!infile.eof() && cnz<nnz)
        {
            infile>>A[cnz].row>>A[cnz].col>>A[cnz].val;
            A[cnz].row--;
            A[cnz].col--;
            //cout<<A[cnz].row<<" "<<A[cnz].col<<" "<<A[cnz].val<<endl;
            ++cnz;
        }
        std::assert(cnz==nnz);
     }
     infile.close();    
   }
   
   /*assigned the value to m(row),n(column) and nnz(the number of non-zeros)*/
   template <typename ITYPE>
   void init_nnz(std::string fileName,ITYPE& m,ITYPE& n,ITYPE& nnz)
   {
       ITYPE flops;
       std::cout <<"reading input matrix in text(ascii).."<<std::endl;
       std::ifstream infile(fileName.c_str());
       char line[256];
       char c=infile.get();
       while(c=='%')
       {
           infile.getline(line,256);
           c=infile.get();
        }
        infile.unget();
        infile>>m>>n>>nnz;
        infile.close();
    }
    
    /*convert to CSR format*/
    template <class T,class ITYPE>
    void init_csr(Triple<T,ITYPE> * triples,ITYPE *& jc,ITYPE *& ir,T *& num,ITYPE m,ITYPE n,ITYPE size)
    {
        // Constructing empty Csr objects (size = 0) are not allowed.
        assert(size != 0 && n != 0);
        ITYPE * w = new ITYPE[m];   // workspace of size n (# of columns)
    
        for(ITYPE k = 0; k < m; ++k)
            w[k] = 0;
        for (ITYPE k = 0 ; k < size ; ++k) 
        {
            int tmp =  triples[k].row;
            w [ tmp ]++ ;       // column counts (i.e, w holds the "col difference array")
        }
        if(size > 0)
        {
            ir[m] = CumulativeSum (w, m) ;      // cumulative sum of w
            for(ITYPE k = 0; k < m; ++k)
                ir[k] = w[k];
            ITYPE last; 
            for (ITYPE k = 0 ; k < size ; ++k)
            {
                jc[ last = w[ triples[k].row ]++ ]  = triples[k].col ;    
            num[last] = triples[k].val ;
             }
        }
        delete [] w;
     }
        
     /*
      ** convert the file into CSR format
      */
     template <class T,class ITYPE>
     void readFile(std::string name,ITYPE *& jc,ITYPE *& ir,T *& num,ITYPE & m,ITYPE & n,ITYPE &nnz)
     {
         init_nnz<ITYPE>(name,m,n,nnz);
         Triple<T,ITYPE> * A=new Triple<T,ITYPE>[nnz];
         Triple_init<T,ITYPE>(name,A);
         init_csr(A,jc,ir,num,m,n,nnz);
     }
#endif
```

the makefile is below:

```
NVIDIA = $(HOME)/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples
CUDA = /usr/local/cuda-5.0
CUSP = /home/taoyuan/setup_package
NVIDINCADD = -I$(NVIDIA)/common/inc
CUDAINCADD = -I$(CUDA)/include 
CC = -L/usr/lib64/ -lstdc++

GCCOPT = -O2 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions 
INTELOPT = -O3 -fno-rtti -xW -restrict -fno-alias
SPMV = $(CUSP)/cusp/detail/device/spmv
#DEB = -g
#NVCC = -G
#ARCH = -arch=sm_20
ARCH = -arch=sm_35

csr:csr.cu
    nvcc $(DEB) $(NVCC)  $(ARCH) $(CC) -lm  $(NVIDINCADD) -I$(CUSP) -I$(SPMV) -I$(THRUST)  -lcusparse -I./ -o $(@) $(<)
```

the OS is redhat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2, the software is cuda-5.0 and thrust 1.5.1 which is setup at directory named "/home/taoyuan/setup_package", GPU is k20M.

while compiling the program, I got the error below:

the error is "fileproc.h(60): error: expected an identifier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `assert` instead of `std::assert` - assert is a macro, so it is not in the std namespace.

Comment: I got error upon your direction:fileproc2.h:61: error: ‘assert’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Add <assert.h> to your includes